# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column for `where` query when using includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following associations:

mobile_application.rb

```
has_many :events
```

event.rb

```
belongs_to :mobile_application
```

The following runs properly:

```
MobileApplication.includes(:events)
#=> MobileApplication Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `mobile_applications`.* FROM `mobile_applications`  ORDER BY created_at desc
#   Event Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`mobile_application_id` IN (746, 745, 744, ....
```

but when I tried with the following,

```
MobileApplication.includes(:events).where("events.expiry_date >= ?", Time.zone.now)
```

it throws an error:

```
MobileApplication Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `mobile_applications`.* FROM `mobile_applications` WHERE (events.expiry_date >= '2019-02-18 07:34:40.738517')  ORDER BY created_at desc
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.expiry_date' in 'where clause': SELECT `mobile_applications`.* FROM `mobile_applications` WHERE (events.expiry_date >= '2019-02-18 07:34:40.738517')  ORDER BY created_at desc
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.expiry_date' in 'where clause': SELECT `mobile_applications`.* FROM `mobile_applications` WHERE (events.expiry_date >= '2019-02-18 07:34:40.738517')  ORDER BY created_at desc
```

**Update**

Please suggest how I can filter it. Using `references` also throws the following error & also got same with answer provided by Marek Lipka,

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'created_at' in 
order clause is ambiguous: SELECT `mobile_applications`.`id` AS t0_r0, 
`mobile_applications`.`name` AS t0_r1, ...
```

I guess it is due to column ambiguity created by `default_scope` present in model to order it by `created_at` which is present in both associated tables.

Comment: It does not seem to be related to references, the `events` table does not have `expiry_date` column.  Have you run the migrations?

Comment: @Sid yes did, I get same error with reference, which I got from solution provided by Marek Lipka. Updating question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `includes` doesn't perform `left join`, it performs two separate DB queries instead. You can force `left join` using `eager_load`, like this:

```
MobileApplication.eager_load(:events).where('events.expiry_date >= ?', Time.zone.now)
```

or, if you in fact don't need eager loading (I don't know that), you can simply use `joins`:

```
MobileApplication.joins(:events).where('events.expiry_date >= ?', Time.zone.now)
```

About the error with using `references` or `eager_load`: You clearly try to do ordering by `created_at` somewhere (though you didn't include this in the question) like:

```
order('created_at DESC')
```

So, obviously, DB doesn't know what table you have in mind with `joins`, because there is `created_at` column both in `mobile_applications` or `events`. So you need to specify the 'target' table, like:

```
order('mobile_applications.created_at DESC')
```

Comment: Yes I need to filter it out (not associated record needed further) so joins worked, I forgot  it & tried only `includes`.

Comment: Tried with `eager_load` but threw same error I got with `includes` with `references` what I added in question update, please check and comment here what possible reason can be for that.

Comment: @ray is it the same error when you use `references` or `eager_load`? What does the DB query look like?

Comment: `joins` is enough for me now but I am curious about further i got in update in question. This I faced previous also for `includes` - `references` used for `undefined column for table` error but later got error column ambiguity error for order('column_name') so I used to provide it by order(`table_name.column_name`)

Comment: @ray I edited my answer to address this issue, please check.

Comment: But why table_name is explicitly needed column is present in both tables? If no table_name is provided it should consider target table in sql query. It can be more advantageous

Comment: It's the question for DB engines developers. But TBH for me it's quite obvious that when you references the column present in at least 2 tables in join query, you have to specify which specific column (i.e. of which table) you have in mind to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

From rails 4.x, you must add keyword `references`:

```
MobileApplication.includes(:events).references(:events).where("events.expiry_date >= ?", Time.zone.now)
```

Comment: `includes` with `references` I used threw column ambiguity error for `created_at`, I guess it is default_scope which fire `order` query. Perhaps `joins` worked for me just to filter it.